# Getting an error regarding - Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource []: Invocation of init method failed;

Tags: java, json, web-services, spring-boot, entity

Building a web service using spring boot. I generated the entity classes and now I keep getting a build failed error on two of the classes I generated out of 9 classes.

I am new to spring boot, I tested the code with an entity class with no relationships and I got back a JSON response. I thinking its a mapping issue of some kind but I'm not 100% sure.

Any help would be grateful.

```
2019-03-08 00:02:35.831  INFO 7816 --- [           main] c.fypwebservice.webservice.Application   : Starting Application on DESKTOP-9UBNL1S with PID 7816 (D:\Repos\webservice\target\classes started by Decla in D:\Repos\webservice)
2019-03-08 00:02:35.833  INFO 7816 --- [           main] c.fypwebservice.webservice.Application   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-03-08 00:02:36.304  INFO 7816 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-03-08 00:02:36.362  INFO 7816 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 53ms. Found 2 repository interfaces.
2019-03-08 00:02:36.602  INFO 7816 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a75777e8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-03-08 00:02:37.114  INFO 7816 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-03-08 00:02:37.135  INFO 7816 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-03-08 00:02:37.136  INFO 7816 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
2019-03-08 00:02:37.146  INFO 7816 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Decla\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.]
2019-03-08 00:02:37.255  INFO 7816 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-03-08 00:02:37.256  INFO 7816 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1391 ms
2019-03-08 00:02:37.439  INFO 7816 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-03-08 00:02:38.087  INFO 7816 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-03-08 00:02:38.167  INFO 7816 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-03-08 00:02:38.217  INFO 7816 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
2019-03-08 00:02:38.218  INFO 7816 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-03-08 00:02:38.325  INFO 7816 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-03-08 00:02:38.442  INFO 7816 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-03-08 00:02:38.611  WARN 7816 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(id) of com.fypwebservice.webservice.model.Record.module referencing com.fypwebservice.webservice.model.Module not mapped to a single property
2019-03-08 00:02:38.611  INFO 7816 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-03-08 00:02:38.619  INFO 7816 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2019-03-08 00:02:38.621  INFO 7816 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-03-08 00:02:38.638  INFO 7816 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-08 00:02:38.641 ERROR 7816 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(id) of com.fypwebservice.webservice.model.Record.module referencing com.fypwebservice.webservice.model.Module not mapped to a single property
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.fypwebservice.webservice.Application.main(Application.java:23) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(id) of com.fypwebservice.webservice.model.Record.module referencing com.fypwebservice.webservice.model.Module not mapped to a single property
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:333) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1827) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1771) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1658) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please share your entity(s) which causes the problem so that we can suggest better

Comment: for some reason it wont leave me add any more code